# Looking for a model/part number for these "male JST wire-to-wire" ends

Tags: identification, connector

Does anyone know what the male end is called (part in the blue square)?

[image: What is this called]

I see them "everywhere" when I look up "JST wire to wire" but I can't seem to find an actual model/part number or official listing on JST's site. The product pages/datasheets for the JST PH/XH/EH series don't seem to list these either; the only male ends listed are the male headers that are for wire-to-board connections.

Even [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4872) seems to carry it, but their product page doesn't list an actual model/part number either, but just points to the JST XH datasheet (which does not list them).

I'd like to use these (and hoping there is a higher current version as well) but would prefer to have a model/part number for reference (as well as the model/part number for the crimp pin if applicable).

---

It may be worth mentioning that there does seem to be this variant where it looks like they just took the normal male end meant for a board, straightened out the leads, and soldered to them:

[image: Not what I want]

Functionally the same, but I'm not really interested in these.

Comment: Not sure about those exact ones, but Digikey calls those types of connectors 'Free Hanging (In-Line)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the official JST connectors are strictly wire-to-board for those series, which is why you will see pigtail harnesses that have wires soldered to the PCB connector. There are a lot of companies in China making compatible equivalents like what you've found, but the part numbering is going to be completely dependent on whoever is making them and often that is not available.

It sounds like you may be open to other options so I'll give a couple that I've used before:

- JST sells the [SM series](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=238) as a wire-to-wire solution which are also fairly popular for hobbyist use (particularly for RGB LED strips). This series is strictly wire-to-wire but is much easier to connect and disconnect than the XH series due to the latch design.
- Another option that is less abundant (but is a higher performing connector) is the JST JWPF series. These are available in both [wire-to-wire](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=152) and [wire-to-board](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=151) versions. These are IPx7 rated and the PCB mount connector can be used for open face potting applications

Comment: Thanks confirming what I suspected. I did look at the SM series, but I was actually trying to find a family that included wire to wire and wire to board. I ended up going with "something" that resembles molex's nanofit line (the factory called it "JST 3.0" which I know is wrong). The JST JWPF looks pretty interesting (seems to fulfill my wire-wire + wire-board requirement too). I'll have to place it on my list of connectors to look at next. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: JST connectors are usually referenced from one pin to the next pin. If you know what you need there, that might help you narrow down the search results.